# Testcafe: finding elements with mutiple conditions

Tags: selector, testcafe

I'm trying to create a selector that matches "several" items in my dom.

Dom may look like this:

```
   <a class="email-item">
    <span class="title">Newsletter</span>
    <span class="from">a@a.com</span>
   </a>
   <a class="email-item">
    <span class="title">Newsletter</span>
    <span class="from">a@a.com</span>
   </a>
   <a class="email-item">
    <span class="title">Newsletter</span>
    <span class="from">b@b.com</span>
   </a>
```

I try to find all a-elements that do have the title "Newsletter" as innerText AND are from "a@a.com"

so kind of a combo-selector...

Thanks for your help!
Ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [filter](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402753/reference/test-api/selector/filter) method to find elements that match the conditions.

Comment: i'm kind of new to testcafe... gonna look into .filter() now.